# Do the comic adaptions of the Ender stories introduce new material?

Tags: comics, enders-game

Some of the *Ender* comics are new stories (*Recruiting Valentine*, *Formic Wars*, etc), while others cover the same material as the novels (*Ender's Game: Battle School*, *Ender's Shadow: Battle School*, *Ender's Game: Command School*, *Ender's Show: Command School*, *Ender in Exile*, *Speaker for the Dead*).

Do any of these comics that are telling the same stories as the novels introduce new material into the Ender-verse?  If I've read all the novels, then do I know everything that the comics contain?

Answer (score 2):

The "Formic Wars" comics contain new material that is not in the books. They are prequel stories.  Here is the publisher description for "Formic Wars: Burning Earth" (7 issues originally):

The never-before-told prequel to ENDER'S GAME! An unidentified ship is rocketing toward Earth with tech far beyond anything we've ever seen, and the only people who can give warning are a small band of asteroid miners millions of miles from home. The clock is ticking, and it doesn't look good for the human race. From New York Times-bestselling author Orson Scott Card comes the tale of humanity's first contact with the Formics - and the horrible toll it took on mankind.

This is followed up by the 5 issue "Formic Wars: Silent Strike":

With 44 million people killed by the toxic gas the alien Formics unleashed in China, the only hope of a counter-agent lies with Mazer Rackham and the Mobile Operations Police safely retrieving a sample. Meanwhile, young asteroid miner Victor Delgado has snuck aboard the Formic mothership in hopes of taking it down alone - and boy is he is for a big disappointment. Meanwhile, Captain O'Toole and his unit take on the Formic Death Squads, but the humans are outnumbered a hundred to one! Besieged on all sides, the Formics fight to the bitter end - but as the Hegemon of Earth is revealed, is it truly the end after all?

Comment: Just finished reading Shadows in Flight, and that toxic gas is mentioned in it. (I do not recall it mentioned in any of the other canon books).  PS: Excellent ending to the series, very well handled.

Comment: @geoffc : no ending yet, there's going to be a *Shadows Alive* that will reunite Lusitania with the Shadows Saga... Also, the toxic gas now appears in canon during the new prequel novels: *Earth Unaware* and/or *Earth Afire*.